# 'Error when checking target' message when trying to train with VGG16 model

Tags: python, keras, transfer-learning

I am a beginner to transfer learning,
In this project i aimed to use VGG16 and add some more layers to do a classification between 2 classes: class0 and class1

I have dataframe named 'train' with 'id' column contains file names while label contains class of that image

Images and prepared through ImageDataGenerator() and flow.from_dataframe

To summarise, the last layer of mine was Dense(2,activation='softmax')

The input image to VGG16 has shape of (32,32,3)

However, it kepts being error:

**ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_55 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 32, 32, 3)**

A summary of my model:

[Here](https://www.kaggle.com/lexuanhieu131297/simple-cnn-model-for-labelling?scriptVersionId=11962205) was my jupyter notebook for training.

what is wrong with my coding here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that your network's output has two dimensions (as the summary shows, output shape is `(None, 2)`), but your label has shape `(1, 32, 32, 3)`.

In your validation data generation, you set `class_mode="input"`. This means that your labels will also be images of the same shape as your input (see doc https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#flow_from_dataframe) instead of being 2 dimensional classification labels. This is the problem. Use `class_mode="categorical"` as you used for the training data.

Comment: Thank you, your notes solved my issues. Thank you so much